# How can I pass values between a Dialog and an Activity?

Tags: java, android, variables, dialog

I am asking the user for input via a Dialog:

```
package com.android.cancertrials;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class CustomDialog extends Dialog  {


    private String name;
//    private ReadyListener readyListener;
     public static EditText etName;
     public String zip;

    public CustomDialog(Context context, String name) {
        super(context);
        this.name = name;
//        this.readyListener = readyListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mycustomdialog);
        setTitle("Enter the Zip Code ");
        Button buttonOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
        buttonOK.setOnClickListener(new OKListener());
        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditZip);
    }

    private class OKListener implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
//            readyListener.ready(String.valueOf(etName.getText()));
            CustomDialog.this.dismiss();
        }
    }


}
```

When the user hits OK, how can I pass the value that was entered in the textbox, back to a member variable in the Activity that launched it?

Comment: Do you need to create a class that extends dialog? It doesn't look like you're actually doing anything special with the dialog that requires a subclass.

Comment: I guess not? Can you provide me an example of how to use the standard AlertDialog that holds an EditText? How would I grab that info and pass to the calling activity?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can do that in different ways... actually, if your dialog has only an "OK" button to dismiss, why don't you just create a custom dialog using the `AlertDialog.Builder` class instead of subclassing `Dialog`?

Anyway... let's suppose you have good reasons to do it the way you did it. In that case, I'd use the ObserverPattern. Something like this:

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog  {


    private String name;
     public static EditText etName;
     public String zip;
    OnMyDialogResult mDialogResult; // the callback

    public CustomDialog(Context context, String name) {
        super(context);
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // same you have
    }

    private class OKListener implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if( mDialogResult != null ){
                mDialogResult.finish(String.valueOf(etName.getText()));
            }
            CustomDialog.this.dismiss();
        }
    }

    public void setDialogResult(OnMyDialogResult dialogResult){
        mDialogResult = dialogResult;
    }

    public interface OnMyDialogResult{
       void finish(String result);
    }
}
```

On your activity:

```
CustomDialog dialog;
// initialization stuff, blah blah
dialog.setDialogResult(new OnMyDialogResult(){
    public void finish(String result){
        // now you can use the 'result' on your activity
    }
});
```

Reading your code it seems you already tried something similar.

#### Edit: doing it the easy way

You can still use your `mycustomdialog` layout. And this is how you would use the `AlertDialog.Builder`:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(YourActivity.this);
final View yourCustomView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mycustomdialog, null);

final TextView etName = (EditText) yourCustomView.findViewById(R.id.EditZip);
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this)
    .setTitle("Enter the Zip Code")
    .setView(yourCustomView)
    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            mSomeVariableYouHaveOnYourActivity = etName.getText().toString();
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).create();
dialog.show();
```

Comment: Thanks for the very descriptive post. For the sake of learning, and simplicity, how would I also go about performing the same thing using the AlertDialog.Builder?

Comment: Allow 10 mins... I will write it that way.

Comment: Also, in your first example -- I don't see where I can pull out etName.getText()? That is essentially my "result"

Comment: Look closer... search for this line: `mDialogResult.finish(String.valueOf(etName.getText()));`. Isn't the observer pattern just awesome?... I love it!

Comment: Very awesome. Thanks Cristian, I learned a lot this morning! Both ways are excellent, for the sake of simplicity and less LOC, I will implement the Builder.

Comment: @Cristian - in you example the variable "mSomeVariableYouHaveOnYourActivity" you meant a static variable in activity class ? is static variable good to work with? Other day I just say in google IO video, they were saying "No No" to static variable.

Comment: `mSomeVariableYouHaveOnYourActivity` should not be static

Comment: @Cristian I'm trying to implement this but, im getting a null reference on my main activity. `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'vDFragment.setDialogResult(com.tech.pad.DFragment$OnMyDialogResult)' on a null object reference`  . ive pretty much got everything you do in the answer. but im not sure why that's null

Answer (score 1):

I achieve this through broadcasting intent from **[dialog]** to **[activity]**.

First passing the activity into the function:

```
public class DialogFactory {

    public static AlertDialog addSomeDialog(Activity activity) {
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  if (SOMETHING_IS_TRUE) {

                      // prepare your parameters that need to be sent back to activity
                      Intent intent = new Intent(IntentAction.INTENT_ADD_TASK);
                      intent.putExtra(IntentConst.PARAM_A, aInput);
                      intent.putExtra(IntentConst.PARAM_B, bInput);
                      activity.sendBroadcast(intent);

                      Toast.makeText(activity, "Something is TRUE!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  } else {
                      Toast.makeText(activity, "Something NOT TRUE!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Call above function when some option menu or button clicked in your activity.

Then prepare your activity to receive the intent with BroadcastReceiver in the activity:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction() == IntentAction.INTENT_ADD_TASK) {
             // Do whatever you want to refresh the layout or anything in the activity
             // or even ask fragments inside to act upon it.
             .....
        }
    }
};
```

Don't forget to register & un-register the receiver:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(IntentAction.INTENT_ADD_TASK));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of any public variables of your dialog class in onDismiss listener like this

```
SaveRecordedFileDialogClass cdd = new SaveRecordedFileDialogClass(this,extraVariable);
cdd.setOnDismissListener(new 
DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            myPublicActivityVar=cdd.anyTypevariable;
        }
});
cdd.show();
```