# Using observerpattern for interfacing with DialogFragment, nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, observer-pattern, android-dialogfragment

This is my first post here, so be gentle.

**What I am trying to acheive:** Using a custom Dialog (extending DialogFragment). Retreiving data from that dialog using ObserverPattern.

**What I have tried yet:** Following this great way of doing it from Christian https://stackoverflow.com/a/4279847/2274526

**What works:**Dialog shows, in its full beauty.

**What fails:** When buttonOK is clicked, I get a nasty nullpointerexception on the Interface-holding variable inside my Dialog.

**Why I need your help:**Isn't that obvious? Just kidding. I have searched The World Wide Web for answers, but none has fulfilled my wish of exceptionless code. The code does not give med any errors before runtime. I believe that the problem lies in the calling of setDialogResult.

Inside my MainActivity.

```
dialog = new AddEmployerDialog();
    FragmentManager frmngr = getFragmentManager();
    empMngr = new EmployeeManager(this);


    dialog.show(frmngr, "dialog");
    dialog.setDialogresult(new OnDialogFinished(){
        public void finish(Employer newEmp){
            empMngr.addEmployer(newEmp);

        }
```

This is not my complete, but hopefully what you need from my dialogclass.

```
public class AddEmployerDialog extends DialogFragment {

public OnDialogFinished mDialogFinished; 

EditText txtName;
EditText txtPhone;
EditText txtEmail;
EditText txtSalary;


public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(this.getTag(), "OnCreate Was called");
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();  

    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_emp_dialog, null))
    // Add action buttons
           .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   //if(mDialogFinished !=null)
                   //   {
                //TODO Fix null exception of mDialog
                            Log.i("I came to onclick",dialog.getClass().toString());
                          mDialogFinished.finish(new Employer(String.valueOf(txtName.getText()), 
                                  String.valueOf(txtEmail.getText()), 
                                  String.valueOf(txtSalary.getText()), 
                                  String.valueOf(txtPhone.getText())));
                    //  }     
                          Log.i("and now after add",dialog.getClass().toString());
                          AddEmployerDialog.this.dismiss();
            }


           })
           .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   AddEmployerDialog.this.getDialog().cancel();
               }
           }); 



    return builder.create();
}

private void instaViews() {
    txtName=(EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.dialog_txt_new_emp_name);
    txtPhone=(EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.dialog_txt_new_emp_phone);
    txtEmail=(EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.dialog_txt_new_emp_email);
    txtSalary=(EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.dialog_txt_new_emp_salery);

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AddObListAdapter adapter = new AddObListAdapter(getActivity());
     ListView list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lstOB);
     list.setAdapter(adapter);
     instaViews();

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
public interface OnDialogFinished{
       void finish(Employer newEmp);
    }
public void setDialogresult(OnDialogFinished onDialogFinished) {
    mDialogFinished = onDialogFinished;

}
```

}

Logcat output:

```
03-23 22:54:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(23076): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-23 22:54:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(23076): Process: se.ludvig.hourly, PID: 23076
03-23 22:54:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(23076): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-23 22:54:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(23076):    at     se.ludvig.hourly.GUI.AddEmployerDialog$1.onClick(AddEmployerDialog.java:43)
03-23 22:54:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(23076):    at    com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
03-23 22:54:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(23076):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-23 22:54:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(23076):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-23 22:54:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(23076):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
03-23 22:54:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(23076):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-23 22:54:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(23076):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-23 22:54:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(23076):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
03-23 22:54:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(23076):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
03-23 22:54:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(23076):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please add the logcat output so that we can analyze the NullPointerException stacktrace

Comment: @donfuxx Logcat added!

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
mDialogFinished.finish(new Employer(String.valueOf(txtName.getText()),
```

you are trying to call the method `finish` of mDialogFinished, but you have never initialized it before, you just declared the field:

```
public OnDialogFinished mDialogFinished;
```

==> NPE

Comment: Thanks for your @donfuxx reply, hmm, but doesn't I initialize mDialogFinished when calling setDialogResult from MainActivty? "public void setDialogresult(OnDialogFinished onDialogFinished) {
  mDialogFinished = onDialogFinished;}" I can not initialize a interface in dialogclass?

Comment: I have overseen that, but I am not sure if that is the best way to do it. Just to be sure, is this line 43: `mDialogFinished.finish(new Employer(String.valueOf(txtName.getText()),` ? Try checking values of mDialogFinished and txtName in debugger.

Comment: Hm yes now it seems like the NPE shows up when trying to log out my editexts, I have tried to instatiate them using this method from within my Dialogclass      txtName=(EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.dialog_txt_new_emp_name);    Is this way incorrect?:) Edit: My Interface didn't give me NPE this time :)

Comment: I have just read through the [link that you posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279787/how-can-i-pass-values-between-a-dialog-and-an-activity/4279847#4279847) in your question and the author of the linked answer surrounds his interface method call with a `if( mDialogResult != null ){` nullcheck.. I guess he had a reason for that ;-)

Comment: Hehe yes ofcourse, but still, he didn't deal with null, therefore that is just cosmetica, I´ll have to checkout how to deal with Views from within the dialog, I am very thankful for your time and help!