# Dialog fire non-static methods in main activity

Tags: java, android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I have a dialog that adds items to a `listview`, and when an item is added I need to reset the list adapter (because if not things get weird).

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279787/how-can-i-pass-values-between-a-dialog-and-an-activity) that I can create an event listener and listen to it in the main activity. I tried doing so but it gives me errors.

**AddMovieDialog.java:**

```
public class AddMovieDialog extends DialogFragment {
  private OnFinishListener onFinishListener;

  @Override
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_movie_dialog, null))
           .setTitle("Add a movie")
           .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // stuff

                    if (!movieName.isEmpty()) {
                        // stuff

                        if (AddMovieDialog.this.onFinishListener != null)
                            AddMovieDialog.this.onFinisheListener.finish();
                    }
               }
           });

    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();

  }

  public void setOnFinishListener(OnFinishListener listener) {
      this.onFinishListener = listener;
  }

  public interface OnFinishListener {
      void finish();
  }
}
```

**In the MainActivity:**

```
AddMovieDialog addMovieDialog = new AddMovieDialog();
addMovieDialog.setOnFinishListener(new OnFinishListener() {
    public void finish() {

    }
});
```

But it gives me a compilation error: "The method setOnFinishListener(new OnFinishListener(){}) is undefined for the type AddMovieDialog"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call a method which is non-static using the object. You can't call it using just the class name.

Change to this

```
AddMovieDialog addMovieDialog = new AddMovieDialog();
addMovieDialog .setOnFinishListener(new OnFinishListener() {
    public void finish() {

    }
});
```

Also shouldn't

```
if (AddMovieDialog.this.onCloseListener != null)
    AddMovieDialog.this.onCloseListener.finish();
```

be

```
if (AddMovieDialog.this.onFinishListener != null)
    AddMovieDialog.this.onFinishListener.finish();
```

**EDIT**
Seem your import statement in `MainActivity` is wrong. It should be something like `com.yourpackagename.AddMovieDialog.OnFinishListener`

Comment: Oh sorry I just noticed it. That's not the problem, I accidentally put it like that here. There is still an error. 
Yup, that too. It's still the same error, when I copied the code I changed some things and it got mixed up. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Check your import in `MainActiviy`. It should be `com.yourpackagename.AddMovieDialog.OnFinishListener `