# How do I pass arguments to a Dialog box in Android?

Tags: android

Google decided to make a single-threaded user interface that doesn't have modal dialogs.  I'm sure most of you have found that nothing updates until your function returns because everything is event driven on a single thread (by "law").

If I have a simple alert-box, such as "Are You Sure?" (example only), with a Yes and No button, then I have to assign callbacks to the buttons rather than having a simple return value (no modal dialogs).  That's fine, even though a return value would vastly simplify my problem (arguments stay local to the caller), although this would stop the calling activity from responding (modal).

Imagine now if I have a list of items and the user attempts to perform some operation.  The dialog must now have some way to pass WHICH item I want to perform the operation on to the button's callback, but I can't seem to find any mechanism in the API for passing this along to the onclick handler.  Using non-local variables is a work-around, but messy.

How can I pass this information along cleanly?  Does anyone have some sort of hack that would somehow "fake" a modal dialog that can return a value (I'm not seeing how).

Comment: Are you talking about http://www.101apps.co.za/articles/making-a-list-coding-multiple-choice-list-dialogs.html ??

Comment: No.  In this specific instance, I have a ListView filled by an SQL adapter.  The list item represents a deck of flashcards.  A swipe gesture can delete a deck.  The code first checks to be sure that the deck doesn't have cards in it and warns the user about how many cards are about to be deleted.  I need to propogate which deck is to be deleted from the caller of the dialog into the callback that will run when the OK button is pressed.  There are other situations, but this is one example.

Comment: The same thing represented in tutorial, you have to maintain list items as per user interaction with your dialog's List then on OK button press you have to pass that local variables to particular function to further action. I think you can understand this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom dialog that extends the default android Dialog and add the information you need and pass on the constructor.
See more here: [How can I pass values between a Dialog and an Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279787/how-can-i-pass-values-between-a-dialog-and-an-activity)

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer since its the one I started using (even before you replied).  It still seems somewhat clumsy to have to extend the dialog just to be able to forward on a parameter, but I suppose that's the best it will get without relying an external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly what do you want to achieve. Not sure if your problems is in the communication between the activity to the dialog or dialog to the activity or both.

Anyway, I have some experience on Android and I really recommend you to achieve the communication between activities, fragments, even dialog (DialogFragments) to use one of these libraries. At the beggining could be a little bit hard to understand how work, but the result is faster and cleaner code, of course offers you more flexibility.

Take a look to:

https://github.com/beworker/tinybus --> less used but it is awesome

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus --> more extended and used for the community

Hope to help you!

Answer (score 0):

In a situation like this, I Created a new string array entry in the strings.xml in values folder like this:

```
<string-array name="array">
<item>1</item>
<item>2</item>
</string-array>
```

And then create a dialog using Dialog builder like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater infl=this.getLayoutInflater();
Resources res=getResources();

dialog.setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.alphabets, 0,new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        mReturnVariable=which;          
    }
});
dialog.create().show();
```

So the mReturnVariable contains the user selected item index .Hope that solves the problem

Comment: That's the way to go. One small annotation - this is not a custom dialog, it's a standard AlertDialog.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem.  I don't need to pass constants.  IMHO, this is basically just using global variables with enough window dressing and complications so that it doesn't look like a global variable, and not as convenient.

Comment: @EvanLanglois If you are really concerned in returning the variable then you can create a class method and send the index of the  selected item to that method and in that method you can just return the variable. I'm not aware of how you actually want to access this variable hence said the above method.

Comment: See Listview example.  In other APIs, you could use a modal alert that returns which button was pressed (yes or no for example) and the alert returns back to the calling function, so you don't need to go through hoops to get the local variables into a button callback.   You can't do this in Android since you can't let a function block.

Comment: Ok got the scenario where you want to use this, if i find any hack as you specified will come back

Answer (score 0):

I passed the required arguments to the Alert Dialog using View Binding in Android Latest version.

```
private ConnectDialogBinding connectDialogBinding;
private String chargerID;

private void connectDialog() {
    // Create the object of
    // AlertDialog Builder class
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ConnectActivity.this);
    connectDialogBinding = ConnectDialogBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    builder.setView(connectDialogBinding.getRoot());
    connectDialogBinding.txtID.setText(chargerID);
    builder.setCancelable(false);

    // Create the Alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

    // Show the Alert Dialog box
    alertDialog.show();

    connectDialogBinding.cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alertDialog.cancel();
        }
    });
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0aRO.png)