# Activity not receiving callback from DialogFragment interface

Tags: java, android, interface, android-alertdialog

I know this is a pretty common question, however, I have looked through quite a few similar posts, followed a several guides, and still can't get this to work.

The following is my code for the main activity:

```
NavigationView mDrawerList = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.main_navigation);

    Menu navMenu = mDrawerList.getMenu();
    topChannelMenu = navMenu.addSubMenu("Stuff");
    final Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_button);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyDialog addDialog = new MyDialog();
            addDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "AddDialog");
            addDialog.setDialogResult(new AddDialog.MyDialogListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDialogPositiveClick(MyObject objectToSend) {
                    topChannelMenu.add(objectToSend.toString()); //Not getting called
                    Log.d(TAG, "Item added");
                }
            });


        }
    });
```

As you can see, a button is pressed (located in the navigation drawer), which opens a dialog (relevant class included below). A user inputs some data, and pressed a positive dialog button, which should prompt the data to be sent to the activity. I tried to use the solution recommended in this answer: [How can I pass values between a Dialog and an Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279787/how-can-i-pass-values-between-a-dialog-and-an-activity) . I know I can probably use an Intent, but I would really like to implement the Observer Pattern, as it's something I've been struggling to understand.

The following is the code for MyDialog:

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {


 MyDialogListener mListener;

public interface MyDialogListener{
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(MyObject objectToSend);
}
@Override
@NonNull
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_plant_dialog, null);
    edit1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.res1_edit);
    edit2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.res2_edit);
    edit3 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.res3_edit);
    builder.setView(view);
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.add, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String selectedName = edit1.getText().toString();
                    String selectedSpec = edit2.getText().toString();
                    String selectedTemp = edit3.getText().toString();
                    MyObject userObject = new Plant(selectedName, selectedSpec);
                    mDBHandler = new DBHandler(getActivity(), null, null, 1); 
                    mDBHandler.addToDB(userObject);
                    mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(userObject);


                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                }
            });


    //return createdDialog;
    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // Verify that activity implements the listener
    try {
        // Instantiate the MyDialogListener so we can send events to host
        mListener = (MyDialogListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e){
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement " +
                "MyDialogListener interface");
    }
}

public void setDialogResult(MyDialogListener listener){
    mListener = listener;
}
}
```

I'm not too great at using interfaces, so I'm not sure if this is a simple mistake of not implementing a method correctly, or if this is something more subtle having to do with the lifecycle of the DialogFragment. I really appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: The line that is commented on the first code snippet is never being executed. onDialogPositiveClick(MyObject objectToSend) is not being called in activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to set the listener explicitly through a method. Make sure your host activity implements the interface and it will get the reference in the onAttach method in the fragment.

Comment: Yep, that did it. Removed setDialogResult(), and just overrode onDialogPositiveClick(). As I said, I'm still trying to get the hang of implementing interfaces, so I appreciate your help!