# Unable to update recycler view due to static and non static method conflict

Tags: android, static, android-recyclerview

I created a recycler view that gets data from sqlite database. I had a small dialog containing two edit texts and after pressing positive button these values are stored in database and I want my recycler view to get updated according to these new values...For that I created a method in MyAdapter.java file and that does this job...

```
package bk.acs.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

import bk.acs.R;

/**
 * Created by bk on 01-03-2017.
 */

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.Holder>{
    List<ListItem> listdata;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyAdapter(List<ListItem> list, Context c)
    {
        this.inflater=LayoutInflater.from(c);
        listdata=list;
    }

    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.subjects_li,parent,false);
        return new Holder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {
        ListItem item=listdata.get(position);
        holder.subjectName.setText(item.subName);
        holder.serialNo.setText(item.sno);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listdata.size();
    }


    public  void  change(int pos)
    {
        notifyItemInserted(pos-1);
    }


    class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        TextView subjectName;
        TextView serialNo;
        View container;
        public Holder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            subjectName=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.subjectTitle);
            serialNo=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.sno);
            container=itemView.findViewById(R.id.cont_root);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            listdata.remove(getPosition());
            notifyItemRemoved(getPosition());
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see the change method clearly updates the recycler view and I'm calling this method from MyDialog.java

Here it is MyDialog.java

```
package bk.acs.AddingToDatabase;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import bk.acs.R;
import bk.acs.RecyclerView.MyAdapter;
import bk.acs.databases.Main;

/**
 * Created by bk on 27-02-2017.
 */

public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {
    View v;
    EditText et1,et2;
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater=getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_dialog,null);
        et1=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.subjectName);
        et2=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.fname);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setView(v).setPositiveButton("ADD", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                final String subname=et1.getText().toString(),fname=et2.getText().toString();
                Main main=new Main(getActivity(),"subjects_db",1,1);
                contentValues.put("SubjectName",subname);
                contentValues.put("FileName",fname);
                SQLiteDatabase db=main.getWritableDatabase();
                long res=db.insert("subjectsTable",null,contentValues);



                MyAdapter.change(res-1);




                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Number of subjects ="+res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            }
        });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

But my problem is that when I'm calling this from MyDialog.java it is saying you cant call a non-static method from a static context....So I've changed change() to static...Now it is saying you can't call notifyItemInserted() from a static context...Please give me a solution for this guys...Thanks a lot in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be very similar to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4279847/4888701

In android, the observer pattern is your best friend. Basically you use that same pattern to communicate the data to your activity, and then you have the activity update the adapter using your defined method. The same pattern works for pretty much any time you need to pass data around between two different things. When you are working with a bunch of fragments and adapters just remember your Activity is like the commanding officer that bosses everyone around, and all the other pieces can communicate that they want to change something using observer pattern.

Comment: I think this is the cleanest and best practice way to do it. If you are wanting to bypass the activity you could make the adapter the dialoglistener instead.

Comment: Thanks bro...If you don't mind could you suggest some good sources to learn android

Comment: this is the official training guide: https://developer.android.com/training/index.html . It does not have every solution but it is a great starting point. It does include the answer i just gave you just worded different. Other than that if I can't find an answer there I google my problem and if that doesn't turn up anything not confusing i put tutorial on the end of my search.