# How to get Data from Customize Dialog to Activity and pass that Data to recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to get Data from Customize Dialog to `Activity` and pass that Data to `recyclerView`.

I have tried below link but didn't worked,
[How can I pass values between a Dialog and an Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279787/how-can-i-pass-values-between-a-dialog-and-an-activity)

Below is the `Activity` Class

```
public class MutipleResourcesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, AddEachResourceDialog.OnMyDialogResult{

    RecyclerView list_resources;
    ImageView img_addResource;

    private ArrayList<AddResource> resources = new ArrayList<>();
    public AddResourceAdapter resourceAdapter;

    AddEachResourceDialog resourceDialog;

    String result1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.add_multiple_resources);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setContentInsetsRelative(0, toolbar.getContentInsetEnd());
        //toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Enter Timings");



        list_resources = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_multiResources);
        img_addResource = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_addResource);
        img_addResource.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

   private void setAdapter() {

    resourceAdapter = new AddResourceAdapter(resources);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    list_resources.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    list_resources.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());



    AddResource ar = new AddResource(mspinnerValue, mstartTime,mendTime);
    resources.add(ar);
    resourceAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    list_resources.setAdapter(resourceAdapter);

    //resources.add(result1);
}


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.img_addResource:

                try {

                    AddEachResourceDialog addEachResource = new AddEachResourceDialog(this);
                    //addEachResource.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Dialog");
                    addEachResource.show();
                    addEachResource.setWindowSize();

                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void finish(String spinnerValue, String startTime, String endTime) {

        System.out.println("####### spinnerValue : "+spinnerValue);
        System.out.println("####### startTime : "+startTime);
        System.out.println("####### endTime : "+endTime);

        setAdapter();
    }
}
```

Below is my Customize Dialog which has Interface "OnMyDialogResult"

```
public class AddEachResourceDialog extends BaseDialog implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Context context;

    private static DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    private static DateFormat tf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    private Calendar startDateTime, finishDateTime;

    private DatePickerDialog startDatePicker, finishDatePicker;
    private TimePickerDialog startTimePicker, finishTimePicker;


    Spinner spinner_resources;
    EditText edt_startTime, edt_endTime;
    Button btn_save, btn_cancel;

    TextView tv_basicStartDate, tv_basicStartTime, tv_basicFinishDate, tv_basicFinishTime;

    OnMyDialogResult mDialogResult;

    AddResource ads = new AddResource();

    public AddEachResourceDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);

        this.context = context;
    }




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try{
            setContentView(R.layout.add_each_resource);

            setTitle("Add Timings");

            spinner_resources = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_resources);

            tv_basicStartDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_basicStartDate);
            tv_basicFinishDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_basicFinishDate);
            tv_basicStartTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_basicStartTime);
            tv_basicFinishTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_basicFinishTime);

            tv_basicStartDate.setOnClickListener(this);
            tv_basicFinishDate.setOnClickListener(this);
            tv_basicStartTime.setOnClickListener(this);
            tv_basicFinishTime.setOnClickListener(this);

            startDateTime = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
            finishDateTime = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
            finishDateTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

            tv_basicStartDate.setText(df.format(startDateTime.getTime()));
            tv_basicStartTime.setText(tf.format(startDateTime.getTime()));
            tv_basicFinishDate.setText(df.format(finishDateTime.getTime()));
            tv_basicFinishTime.setText(tf.format(finishDateTime.getTime()));


            btn_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
            btn_cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);
            btn_save.setOnClickListener(this);
            btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(this);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.saveBtn:


                    mDialogResult = new OnMyDialogResult() {
                        @Override
                        public void finish(String spinnerValue, String startTime, String endTime) {

                            ads.setName(String.valueOf(spinner_resources.getSelectedItem().toString()));
                            ads.setBasicStartDate(String.valueOf(tv_basicStartDate.getText().toString()));
                            ads.setBasicFinishDate(String.valueOf(tv_basicFinishDate.getText().toString()));

                            ads.setBasicStartTime(String.valueOf(tv_basicStartTime.getText().toString()));
                            ads.setBasicFinishTime(String.valueOf(tv_basicFinishTime.getText().toString()));


                            mDialogResult.finish(ads.getName(), ads.getBasicStartDate() +":"+ads.getBasicStartTime(), ads.getBasicFinishDate() +":"+ads.getBasicFinishTime());



                            mDialogResult.finish(ads.getName(), ads.getStartTime(), ads.getEndTime());

                        }
                    };                 

                AddEachResourceDialog.this.dismiss();

                break;

            case R.id.cancelBtn:
                //onBackPressed();
                AddEachResourceDialog.this.dismiss();


                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    public void setDialogResult(OnMyDialogResult dialogResult){
        mDialogResult = dialogResult;
    }

    public interface OnMyDialogResult{
        //void finish(AddEachResourceDialog result);
        void finish(String spinnerValue, String startTime, String endTime);
    }
}
```

Not getting the data from Dialog to `Activity` and I have to pass that data to `recyclerview`. Please help me with this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried using an Interface?

Comment: Yes, In Customize Dialog it has Interface, but the data in not passing from customizeDialog to Activity.Please help me with this @edwin

Comment: someone had a similar issue to yours, check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279787/how-can-i-pass-values-between-a-dialog-and-an-activity?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I have referred the same link which you have mentioned but didn't worked out.

Comment: You should be able to get data from the custom dialog to your activity if you are using an interface. Did you try to use a break point to check if your code ever trigger the finish() methods that you are overriding?

Comment: It is not calling finish() @edwin

Comment: Means there's something wrong with the interface that you had implemented. Btw you should try something like 

((AddEachResourceDialog.OnMyDialogResult) getActivity).finish(ads.getName(), ads.getBasicStartDate() +":"+ads.getBasicStartTime(), ads.getBasicFinishDate() +":"+ads.getBasicFinishTime());

Comment: Assuming your dialog is within the same context of your activity.

Comment: Above code is also not working edwin.May you please check the code posted .

Comment: Btw I think your issue lies in the .finish() method you are calling. It doesn't seems to me that you are actually calling the overridden method in the activity but instead you are calling the dialog class finish() method. Hence you don't get anything as it's recursive of it's own class. You need to get a reference of the activity that is overriding the .finish() method in your custom dialog and use that reference to override the method in your custom dialog.

Comment: I have changed the method even though it didn't worked.Can you please help me on this edwin.

Comment: Are you even able to do getActivity()?

Comment: No, getActivity() is not working in my Activity class

Comment: I mean calling that in your custom dialog.

Comment: No, getActivity() is not working in my custonDialog as well

Comment: I have posted the answer

Comment: edwin didn't worked.No luck

Comment: it should work cause I have tested it on my end though.

Comment: edwin it is not working.May you please look into the code.Callback method is not calling from customDialog.

Answer (score 0):

Change next code:

```
public class AddEachResourceDialog extends BaseDialog implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Context context;

    private static DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    private static DateFormat tf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    private Calendar startDateTime, finishDateTime;

    private DatePickerDialog startDatePicker, finishDatePicker;
    private TimePickerDialog startTimePicker, finishTimePicker;


    Spinner spinner_resources;
    EditText edt_startTime, edt_endTime;
    Button btn_save, btn_cancel;

    TextView tv_basicStartDate, tv_basicStartTime, tv_basicFinishDate, tv_basicFinishTime;

    OnMyDialogResult mDialogResult;

    AddResource ads = new AddResource();

    public AddEachResourceDialog(MutipleResourcesActivity activity) {
        super(activity);

        mDialogResult = activity;
    }




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try{
            setContentView(R.layout.add_each_resource);

            setTitle("Add Timings");

            spinner_resources = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_resources);

            tv_basicStartDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_basicStartDate);
            tv_basicFinishDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_basicFinishDate);
            tv_basicStartTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_basicStartTime);
            tv_basicFinishTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_basicFinishTime);

            tv_basicStartDate.setOnClickListener(this);
            tv_basicFinishDate.setOnClickListener(this);
            tv_basicStartTime.setOnClickListener(this);
            tv_basicFinishTime.setOnClickListener(this);

            startDateTime = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
            finishDateTime = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
            finishDateTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

            tv_basicStartDate.setText(df.format(startDateTime.getTime()));
            tv_basicStartTime.setText(tf.format(startDateTime.getTime()));
            tv_basicFinishDate.setText(df.format(finishDateTime.getTime()));
            tv_basicFinishTime.setText(tf.format(finishDateTime.getTime()));


            btn_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
            btn_cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);
            btn_save.setOnClickListener(this);
            btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(this);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.saveBtn:

ads.setName(String.valueOf(spinner_resources.getSelectedItem().toString()));
                            ads.setBasicStartDate(String.valueOf(tv_basicStartDate.getText().toString()));
                            ads.setBasicFinishDate(String.valueOf(tv_basicFinishDate.getText().toString()));

                            ads.setBasicStartTime(String.valueOf(tv_basicStartTime.getText().toString()));
                            ads.setBasicFinishTime(String.valueOf(tv_basicFinishTime.getText().toString()));

//Which one you need?
                            mDialogResult.finish(ads.getName(), ads.getBasicStartDate() +":"+ads.getBasicStartTime(), ads.getBasicFinishDate() +":"+ads.getBasicFinishTime());

                            mDialogResult.finish(ads.getName(), ads.getStartTime(), ads.getEndTime());



                AddEachResourceDialog.this.dismiss();

                break;

            case R.id.cancelBtn:
                //onBackPressed();
                AddEachResourceDialog.this.dismiss();


                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    public void setDialogResult(OnMyDialogResult dialogResult){
        mDialogResult = dialogResult;
    }

    public interface OnMyDialogResult{
        //void finish(AddEachResourceDialog result);
        void finish(String spinnerValue, String startTime, String endTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all comment setDialogResult() method. It looks useless. Secondly  - log after every step. You need to specify where exactly it's not working. Possibly mDialogResult variable is overwritten somewhere that's why it coudn't pass data to activity.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following part of your dialog code,

```
    case R.id.saveBtn:

    ads.setName(String.valueOf(spinner_resources.getSelectedItem().toString()));
    ads.setBasicStartDate(String.valueOf(tv_basicStartDate.getText().toString()));
    ads.setBasicFinishDate(String.valueOf(tv_basicFinishDate.getText().toString()));
    ads.setBasicStartTime(String.valueOf(tv_basicStartTime.getText().toString()));
    ads.setBasicFinishTime(String.valueOf(tv_basicFinishTime.getText().toString()));

    //Use either this finish method or that one, i don't see why did you call 
    //finish() twice  
    mDialogResult.finish(ads.getName(), ads.getBasicStartDate() +":"+ads.getBasicStartTime(), ads.getBasicFinishDate() +":"+ads.getBasicFinishTime());

    mDialogResult.finish(ads.getName(), ads.getStartTime(), ads.getEndTime());


    AddEachResourceDialog.this.dismiss();
    break;
```

Finally in your activity, replace onclick method with this

```
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.img_addResource:

                try {

                    AddEachResourceDialog addEachResource = new AddEachResourceDialog(this);
                    //addEachResource.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Dialog");
                    addEachResource.setDialogResult(this);
                    addEachResource.show();
                    addEachResource.setWindowSize();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }

    }
```

And you are all good.

Comment: did you put your setDialogResult(this)  method after                AddEachResourceDialog addEachResource = new AddEachResourceDialog(this); ?

Comment: It is not taking in Activity class Jaydeep.May you help me on this please.

Comment: @Naveen i have edited my answer are you sure your on click looks exactly like this? because it should work if the code is like this.

Comment: I have tried with the above code, didn't worked out.No luck Jaydeep

Comment: you can put debug points and check if finish() method is called.

Answer (score 0):

After discussing and looking through the codes a multiple times. I'm certain that .finish() methods that is being called in the custom dialog is not being overridden in the activity class. Which explain why data isn't being passed. What needed to be done is getting a reference of your activity and call the .finish() method to override the method as it is in the activity instead of the custom dialog.

This will cast the context which was init in the MutipleResourcesActivity that was implementing the OnMyDialogResult interface and calls the override method of .finish in the activity. Please use this in your custom dialog class. (the casting is possible if the current context is an activity that implements OnMyDialogResult interface).

```
((AddEachResourceDialog.OnMyDialogResult) context).finish(ads.getName(), ads.getBasicStartDate() +":"+ads.getBasicStartTime(), ads.getBasicFinishDate() +":"+ads.getBasicFinishTime());
```

Comment: Hi edwin, finally Data in coming but when I add data 2nd time not setting the data to recylerview.I have edited the post setAdapter is the method setting up the data.

Comment: I don't quite get what you. Anyway did my answer solve your issue? If so, please mark as Answered. If not, please post the answer that answered your question. If you have any other questions please post another question.