# How to get data from custom dialog and create a new item in recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, dialog

I need to click on fab and the custom dialog will be called. So, how to get data from dialog(DialogFragment) and to create a new item in recyclerview, which has this data?

Edited: Now I have NullPointerException. The code is here:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    adapter = new UserAdapter(users, this);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            createDialog();
        }
    });
}

public void createDialog(){
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_user, null, false);
    final EditText username = view.findViewById(R.id.username);
    final EditText pass = view.findViewById(R.id.password);
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Title")
            .setView(view)
            .setPositiveButton("Add", null)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .setCancelable(false);

    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

    dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                //update RecyclerView
                users.add(new User(username.toString(), pass.toString()));
                dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: have you worked on any code?

Comment: I have a simple recyclerview and a simple dialog and it seems that the second one will be change

Comment: have you worked on any code with the mindset of what you are trying to accomplish? does your dialog box have a form the user will fill out?

Comment: yes, it has an EditText view

Comment: And your recycler is taking in an arraylist of strings I assume?

Comment: I have a very simple example. This model is divide into model, adapter, dialog and MainActivity. Model has class User which have String name and String password(+ getters and setters). adapter has a class which extends Adapter and has ArrayList of User. dailog has a very basic class which extends DialogFragment. In MainActivity i build recyclerview and findById FloatingActionButton

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279787/how-can-i-pass-values-between-a-dialog-and-an-activity
TLDR use an observer pattern. 
Definitely have a good read of how to do that sort of thing, you'll need it all over the place with Android :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple **AlertDialog** with **RecyclerView** to achieve this. Thanks

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.edit_layout, null, false);
            final EditText editText = view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Title")
                    .setView(view)
                    .setPositiveButton("Add", null)
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                    .setCancelable(false);

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();

            dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //fdgdf
                    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText())) {
                        //update RecyclerView
                        dialog.dismis();
                    } else {
                       //Toast to show empty
                    }
                }
            });
```

`R.layout.edit_layout` contains **EditText**  with id **editText**

Comment: Have you use ArrayList to initialize adapter for RecyclerView? If so then just add new item to arraylist and `notify` adapter about dataset changed

Comment: I need simply add in ArrayList new POJO?

Comment: Using content from dialog, create User POJO and add it to ArrayList and notify

Comment: In your Activity class where your RecyclerView, FAB are. Create a function and paste this code and clicking on FAB call this function to popup the dialog and do the rest

Comment: I created a function but i have NPE, Why?

Comment: Also post log for NPE

Comment: **Observation:** username.toString() not correct, should be username.getText().toString()

Comment: I have an error message: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Comment: show me the code of dialog_user.xml, also update your current code that i suggest

Comment: <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username_dialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password_dialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

Comment: Is there any parent layout or not?

Comment: `<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>`

Comment: use this one and check

Comment: IT WORKS. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you wish a particular form to pop on when fab(floating action button) is clicked and then on completion of this particular form add any item to the recycler view.
Here are the steps to complete these requirements - 

1. Add OnClickListener to the fab and open the dialog.

2. Add the Submit button in the form. Set OnClickListener to it.

3. On Submit Button Click (Do the following steps) Store form info in any form (Make an object of POJO)

4. Add data in Recycler DataSet. Call notifyDataSetChanged on Recycler Adapter.

5. Call dialog.dismiss().

Comment: Can you explain me the second paragraph in detail?

Comment: What do you mean by the second paragraph?